# Working with one-to-many relationships=revised (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Okay....previously I wrote up a simple HTML-CSS-Javascript site.  I then created an empty Django project and tried to put everything in that project.  I created a real mess!
So I am now writing everything up from scratch, working on the Django project first.  I still am having problems with the database I set up.  Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Book(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
description = models.TextField()
source = models.CharField(max_length=200)
source_site = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Chapter(models.Model):
book = models.ForeignKey(
    Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='chapters')
chtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
chtitletext = models.CharField(max_length=200)
chtext = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.chtitle
```

And here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Book, Chapter

def index(request):
book_list = Book.objects.order_by('-id')
output = ', '.join([b.title for b in book_list])
context = {
    'book_list': book_list,
}
return render(request, 'sophia/index.html', context)

def readBook(request, book_id):
book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=book_id)
chapter_list = Chapter.objects.order_by('-id')

context = {'book':book, 'chapter_list':chapter_list}
return render(request, 'sophia/readbook.html', context)
```

and here is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
app_name = 'sophia'
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('<int:book_id>/', views.readBook, 
name='readbook'),
]
```

and finally, my readbook.html:

```
<h1>{{ book }}</h1>
<h3>{{ book.description }}</h3>
<h3>{{ book.source }}</h3>
<h3>{{ book.source_site }}</h3>

<ul>
{% for chapter in chapter_list %}
<li>{{ chapter.chtitle }} -- {{ chapter.chtitletext }} 
 </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Fields from the book model display just fine.  But the chapter_list is including all the chapters in the Chapter model.  I only want the chapters in the book.
(and does anyone know why my book_list and chapter_list are in reverse order?)

Oh and this is a screenshot:

[readBook.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Es8k.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to filter your Chapter queryset as so:

```
chapter_list = Chapter.objects.filter(book=book).order_by('-id')
```

And you may want to add an order_id or a chapter_number field on your Chapter model so you have more control on the order in which they're displayed.

Comment: Thanks Samer.  So I was assuming that the Chapter id would automatically be there, like in the Book id

Answer (score 0):

i think you could put it this way

```
def readBook(request, book_id):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=book_id)
    chapter_list = Chapter.objects.filter(book=book).order_by('-id') # you scpecify wich book the chapters are from
    context = {'book':book, 'chapter_list':chapter_list}
    return render(request, 'sophia/readbook.html', context)
```